# Can PhpStorm disable whole folder Deployments?

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to limit Deployment in PhpStorm to only allow 1 file upload at a time, or disable the ability to upload whole folders?

Comment: There is no such "upload only 1 file" or "prevent folder upload" options: PhpStorm will upload what user will select for upload.

Comment: Please describe the initial problem -- maybe there is another approach to solve your issue.

Comment: We have multiple developers pushing code changes from their IDE to the server. However they're not always pulling changes from git. So a few days may go by and they'll accidently hit upload/deploy and deploy the whole repository not just the file they wanted.

Comment: Why not then disable the Upload (remove shortcut / do not have a default server) and use `Synchronize to deployed...` action .. when user can overview the uploaded/downloaded files before hitting the button?